# Checking if data exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

What is the right way of checking if the required data is in the database?

What I use currently is,

`mysql_query("SELECT anyfield FROM table WHERE field='$data'");`

and then check the if any rows are affected.

But I dont really have any use with the extracted data `anyfield`. 
Eventhough the resource usage is so minor here, what is the right way to check if data exists in a db without extracting any other fields from the table?

Comment: why not use simple count() function.

Comment: that suggestion was for mysql_num_rows right? I updated the question a bit, so now you know what am looking for :)

Comment: One little detail about using of `count()` it's better to use `count(id)` - it is take less time. Or just `select id from table where filed = 'data'`.

Comment: No, what @Zohaib is talking about the standart SQL `count()` function which is the way to go. If you don't need the data, don't bring it back from the database, mysql_num_rows require the rows back. And to do that just use `count()` function in your SQL.

Comment: my aim is make my codes better, like I dont want to extract datas when it isnt needed. So was wondering if existence of `$data` in `field` can be checked without selecting any data from other fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the database count and retrieve the count data from the query.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `field` = ...');
if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
if (mysql_result($result, 0, 0) > 0) {
    // some data matched
} else {
    // no data matched
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE `field` = '".$data."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
    // Rows exist
}
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`field`) as count FROM `table` WHERE `field` = '".$data."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row ['count']){
    // Rows exist
}
```

Comment: lol. You misread the question. I know how to do this, but I dont have any use with `anyfield`. I just have to check if `$data` exists in `field`.

I was asking if this could be done without grabbing `anyfiled` from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure, if I was checking for data, that as little data was returned as possible.

Fetch one field (I usually do `id`) and ensure you use `LIMIT`, eg. `LIMIT 1`... assuming you only want to know if *any* record exists.

Because you're using a PHP variable to find a record, if it suits your situation, you could perhaps do a `LEFT JOIN` on the first SQL line that gets `$data`, but that might just as easily be overkill for what you need.