# I want to match the domain name with the Website URL

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose, I have an URL like `http://www.example.com/page1.html`. In my database I have domain like this `http://example.com/`.

Now, if the domain name exists in the DB, I want to return that in the URL.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide that code above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php check this

Comment: I have URLs in the DB and Match the domain name with that URL and return that URL which matches with domain name

select * from tblimportlinks where import_url like '%http://www.example.com/%'"

Comment: Corrected question language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spliting your answer into two parts:

1. ([php-how-to-get-the-base-domain-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201170/php-how-to-get-the-base-domain-url))

   > $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
2. [Checking if data exist in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119665/checking-if-data-exists-in-database)

   > $result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `field` =
   >   ...'); if (!$result) {
   >       die(mysql_error()); } if (mysql_result($result, 0, 0) > 0) {
   >       // some data matched } else {
   >       // no data matched }

   *. You may need to read more about Database and everything. Just look at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Comment: `mysql_query()` ?? Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly No argue that you are RIGHT. Although as in my defence that's a quote from another website, I do not think we are here to share a prefect code to use in real projects, But we are telling how the question can be solved! (There are always lots of attention point should I write 0 to 100 ? or should I solve the pure problem ?)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $domain_name = parse_url('http://example.com/');
 if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ==  $domain_name['host'])
 {
 // some thing here
  }
```